# How can I generate an entire gradle subproject and have it as a dependency in another project?

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator

So let's say I have the following `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'math-server'
project(':math-server').projectDir = file('math/server')

include 'math-client-gen'
project(':math-client-gen').projectDir = file('math/client')

include 'ai'
```

Now I'd like to not commit the any of the files in math-client-gen (including the build.gradle) since those are generated by a build job in `math-server`:

```
// math/server/build.gradle
task generateClient(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '.'
    inputs.dir('./app')
    inputs.dir('.')
    outputs.dir('../client')
    commandLine './client-generator/generate.sh'
}
```

The generate.sh leverages the [openapi client generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/kotlin.md) for kotlin.

Now the `ai` project relies on the `math-client-gen`:

```
// ai/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile project(':math-client-gen')
}
```

Now I have currently found two suboptimal ways to make this work.

Option 1 is to run `./gradlew :math-server:generateClient` before I'm able to run `./gradlew :ai:build`. This sucks, since you cannot build ai on its own anymore.

Option 2 is to commit the files, which of course also isn't the way it should be.

I'm sure there is a better way to do it with gradle, but I just didn't manage to find it yet. As a compromise, I'd be willing to commit the generated `math-client-gen/build.gradle` if it doesn't work without that.

What's the best solution to this problem?

Note: I also saw something like:

```
    implementation files(layout.buildDirectory.dir('classes')) {
        builtBy 'compile'
    }
```

in the docs, that looks promising, but i'd like to have it for an entire subproject and not just some source files if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ai/build.gradle

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.build.dependsOn(project(":math-client").tasks["generateClient"])
}
```

To automate your first option.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up committing the `build.gradle` of the `math-client-gen` and have this line there:

```
// math/client/build.gradle
compileKotlin {
    dependsOn ':math-server:buildMathClient'
}
```

This ensures that the client is always generated when this project is listed as a dependency somewhere.

Then you can simply add the `math-client-gen` as a dependency in other projects, no additional steps required:

```
// ai/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile project(':math-client-gen')
}
```